# importing makehuman model into blender but it looks different

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, makehuman

I imported my model from makehuman (the right pic) into Blender and looked at the textures (the left pic) but the blender version looks weird, can anyone help me make the left pic (blender) look like the right pic (Makehuman)?

[image]

Comment: Could you show us what you have tried to fix the problem and how it failed?

Comment: I exported the model from Makehuman as a (mhx2) file and then Imported it into Blender as the same (mhx2) file but when I looked at it in Material the model looks nothing like it did in Makehuman

Comment: could it be that you are using blender render?